# Terraform states I am trying to initialized file in an empty directory

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform states I am trying to initialized file in an empty directory which is my local profile: C:\Users
c:\users\a874193\kplabs\sectiontwo.

When I run an ls command it shows the tf file in there and when I look at the .tf file within the actual \sectiontwo folder it does show a more or less empty .tf file.

I am very new to TF, so please break it down to me. Thanks

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-west-2"
    access_key = "---------------"
    secret_key = "----------------------"
}

resource "aws_instance" "kelec2" {
    ami = "ami-0d593311db5abb72b"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
}


resource "aws_eip" "elastic" {
    vpc = true
}
```

With the above I have tried to comment out the 2 resources specified, I also replaced all of this with just this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.37.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Result when trying to run terraform init:

PS C:\Users\a874193\kplabs\sectiontwo> terraform init
Terraform initialized in an empty directory!

with Terraform immediately by creating Terraform configuration files.

Result from ls:

```
PS C:\Users\a874193\kplabs\sectiontwo> ls


    Directory: C:\Users\a874193\kplabs\sectiontwo


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        29/10/2022     18:04                .terraform
-a----        29/10/2022     18:04           1152 .terraform.lock.hcl
-a----        29/10/2022     18:43            310 attributes.tf.bak
-a----        29/10/2022     18:44            156 terraform.tfstate
-a----        29/10/2022     18:44          15786 terraform.tfstate.backup
```

```
PS C:\Users\a874193\kplabs\sectiontwo> ls


    Directory: C:\Users\a874193\kplabs\sectiontwo


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        29/10/2022     18:04                .terraform
-a----        29/10/2022     18:04           1152 .terraform.lock.hcl
-a----        29/10/2022     18:43            310 attributes.tf.bak
-a----        29/10/2022     18:44            156 terraform.tfstate
-a----        29/10/2022     18:44          15786 terraform.tfstate.backup
```

Comment: Terraform is telling you there is no file in the folder ending in the `.tf` file extension. You showed some Terraform code in your question, but you didn't say what file that code was in, and in your `ls` output there are no `.tf` files in the list.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
OK, I ended up adding just the kplabs folder which then showed the sectiontwo folder within the left hand pane.
It has init and produced the correct plan resources.

I think I am getting confused with the folder structure so if anyone can make any sense of why it only works when adding the kplabs folder and not the sectiontwo within the kplabs I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because Terraform does not look into subdirectories. It only considers files in the current directory, which is called a “root module”. Any other subdirectory is treated as a “module” and not included by default.

to run the files in another like the inside of a sub-folder there are commands
like you could use -chdir option:

```
terraform -chdir="./path-to-dir" apply
```

or specify the directory without an option

```
terraform apply [options] ./path-to-dir
```

> By default, terraform init assumes that the working directory already contains a configuration and will attempt to initialize that configuration.

Optionally, init can be run against an empty directory with the -from-module=MODULE-SOURCE option, in which case the given module will be copied into the target directory before any other initialization steps are run.

for more information visit this link[terraform chdir new update](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands#switching-working-directory-with-chdir)